# Error viewing Build definitions in VS 2012 / TFS 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I recently installed VS 2012 update 2 and now I get an error when I click on "Builds" under Team Explorer.  I've tried a repair of update 2.  I'd rather not do a complete reinstall unless I have to, so I'm hoping someone has run into this before.  Any help is appreciated.

```
 System.Exception: The component 'Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Controls.BuildsPageView' does not have a resource identified by the URI '/Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Controls;component/buildspage/buildspageview.xaml'.
    at System.Windows.Application.LoadComponent(Object component, Uri resourceLocator)
    at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Controls.BuildsPageView.InitializeComponent()
    at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Controls.BuildsPage.CreateView(PageInitializeEventArgs e)
    at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Controls.WPF.TeamExplorer.TeamExplorerPageBase.Initialize(Object sender, PageInitializeEventArgs e)
    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamFoundation.Build.BuildsPageVs.Initialize(Object sender, PageInitializeEventArgs e)
    at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Controls.WPF.TeamExplorer.Framework.TeamExplorerPageHost.Initialize(TeamExplorerPageContext context)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you also have the TFS Power Tools and Coderush 12.2.8 installed? If so, there seems to be a conflict between these versions.

Check out this bug report for more details: http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q488684

Installing the latest version of the TFS Power Tools that were released on April 18th fixed it for me.

Comment: Thanks a lot - looks like DevExpress released a patch since I asked the question.