# Visual Studio 2013 Builds window shows error, cannot check-in

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, visual-studio-2013

Using Visual Studio 2013 Update 4, I'm trying to check-in some edits. Right after clicking 'check-in', the check-in is cancelled. Afterwards, the Builds window is empty:

[image: Empty Builds window]

Stacktrace:

```
System.Exception: The component 'Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Controls.BuildsPageView' does not have a resource identified by the URI '/Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Controls;component/buildspage/buildspageview.xaml'.
   at System.Windows.Application.LoadComponent(Object component, Uri resourceLocator)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Controls.BuildsPageView.InitializeComponent()
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Controls.BuildsPage.CreateView(PageInitializeEventArgs e)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Controls.WPF.TeamExplorer.TeamExplorerPageBase.Initialize(Object sender, PageInitializeEventArgs e)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamFoundation.Build.BuildsPageVs.Initialize(Object sender, PageInitializeEventArgs e)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Controls.WPF.TeamExplorer.Framework.TeamExplorerPageHost.Initialize(TeamExplorerPageContext context)
```

After restarting VS2013, the Builds window is normal, until I try another check-in.

A suspect for me is TFS Power Tools 2010. I have it installed, as well as TFS Power Tools 2013, but cannot uninstall it, due to an 'error 1001'. Search online shows up this was a problem for TFS Power Tools 2008, but nothing for TFS Power Tools 2010. All threads I've found so far don't offer a solution for this problem.

Installed tools:

- VS 2013 12.0.31101.00 Update 4
- Resharper 8.2.1
- TFS Power Tools 2010 3.2.40301.0
- TFS Power Tools 2013 12.0.0.0

Any idea what's causing this strange behaviour, and how to solve it?

Comment: Looks like you need to repair Visual Studio 2013 and 2013 Update 4 (in that order). Looks like there is a mismatch between file versions or something similar. I don't suspect TFS Power Tools 2010, I have 3 versions installed side-by-side, that just works.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16113809/736079

Comment: That did it, if you add your suggestion as answer, I'll mark it as such. Also, not a duplicate, as I don't have Coderush installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like there is a mismatch in file versions. Repair Visual Studio 2013 and Visual Studio Update 2013 update 4 in that order to ensure that all files are of the same version.